# What was the first C compiler for the IBM PC?

Tags: history, ibm-pc, c

When did a C compiler first become available for the IBM PC? I have fond memories of Turbo C, but that didn't become available until the mid to late eighties; it definitely wasn't the first one. Languages available at launch seem to have been Basic, assembly and a Pascal byte code system.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first compiler for PC-DOS was [Lattice C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_C), released in June, 1982. This compiler was also distributed under license as Microsoft C v2.0. The Lattice C compiler was very popular and widely ported, available on several 1980s retrocomputers including Amiga, Atari ST, and Sinclair QL. The Lattice compiler was acquired by [SAS Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_Institute) in 1987 and renamed SAS/C.

Watcom C was also popular and widely ported, but was not available for the PC until the late-1980s, around the same time as Borland's Turbo C.

Comment: I remember Watcom and Lattice. I know Digital Research had C (along with many other languages) for CP/M-86. I wonder if that might have have been available to run on the IBM PC earlier than Lattice, though for CP/M-86 and not for PC-DOS at the time.

Comment: DJGPP came much later (1989 I believe) but it was an amazing project. First 32-bit C compiler I ever used.  Those were the days....

Comment: @cbmeeks, same here.  I had a copy that came free with a "Teach yourself C in 21 Days" book.  I seem to remember enjoying using that compiler, can't really remember the details though.

Comment: @Wossname I had that exact same book!  In fact, I still may have it.  :-)  I loved that book.  Almost as much as I loved the game programming book from Diana Gruber.

Comment: @cbmeeks, Diana Gruber's game programming articles were rock solid! I remember learning finite-state-automata from her. Ever heard how she reprimanded Michael Abrash for coming up with the "Mode-X" name?  ;)

Comment: @sgorozco yeah!  I remember reading that.  In fact, it was in the "Zen" book by Abrash (which I also own).  One of the coolest books ever.

Comment: "*distributed under license as Microsoft C v2.0*" What was MS C v1.0?

Comment: Microsoft C V1.0 was also based on Lattice C.

Answer (score 12):

I worked for SAS when it acquired Lattice C in 1983. SAS needed a C compiler so it could port the SAS System to the IBM PC. I was part of a group whose job it was to create a "cross-compiler" that ran on IBM's CMS operating system but generated code for the IBM PC. I was experienced in CMS program development so my job was to write enough of the C standard library (memory management, I/O, etc.) to be able to run the compiler on CMS. Other members of the team included ex-Lattice employees who were familiar with code generation, etc.

SAS/C was a compiler that ran on IBM operating systems that could be used to create executables that ran on CMS and IBM's MVS (now Z/OS) O/S. We leased the compiler very successfully but eventually IBM created its own C compiler that eventually took over.

I worked on that product for 6 or 7 years. It was a lot of fun and I wrote some of the best code in my 30+ year career.

Comment: This is a very interesting anecdote, but I don't see how it answers the question **which C compiler was the first to run on the IBM PC**. You can [edit] your answer to expand on it. Please note that on Stack Exchange, answers should *answer the question as asked*. Supplementary, related material can be interesting, but doesn't replace the answer.

Comment: So you're saying the first compiler on the PC was SAS/C?  Interesting, not one that I've heard of.

Comment: I'm agreeing with mannaggia's answer. SAS bought Lattice C and from it, created SAS/C. As I said, SAS/C ran on IBM mainframe operating systems.